# How to append URL param through controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

In my Rails app I want to forward my users to their personal **sign in page** which is stored in a cookie `:user_subdomain`. So when a user goes to `www.app.com/sign_in`, s/he should be automatically forwarded to `www.app.com/sign_in/mycompany`.

How can this be achieved?

I would like to keep my `sign_in_path` helper method because it's sprinkled all over my app.

If I simply `redirect` the `new` action using `redirect_to sign_in_path(:name => cookies[:user_subdomain])` I end up in a loop.

Thanks for any pointers.

---

```
# routes.rb:

get 'sign_in', :to => 'sessions#new'
```

---

```
 # sessions_controller.rb:

class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    params[:name] ||= cookies[:user_subdomain]
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: Do you need you old `www.app.com/sign_in` or just the new way of signing in ?

Comment: @Nermin: Just the new way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the solution is easy. You do not need to redirect, you just need optional parameter for your routes.

[bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters)

```
# routes.rb:

get 'sign_in(/:company_name)', :to => 'sessions#new'
# This will allow
# /sign_in
# and
# /sign_in/mycompany
# Both will lead to same action and you can keep your helper



# sessions_controller.rb:

class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    params[:company_name] ||= cookies[:user_subdomain]
    # You logic here
  end

...

end
```